# Conditional branches within graphQL resolve

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have a graphQL `RootQueryType` which currently looks like this:

```
const RootQueryType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    accounts: {
      type: graphql.GraphQLList(Account),
      description: 'A list of accounts matching the provided arguments.',
      args: {
        type: {
          type: graphql.GraphQLString
        },
        country: {
          type: graphql.GraphQLString
        },
        currency: {
          type: graphql.GraphQLString
        }
      },
      resolve: (obj, args) => {
        if (args.country === 'US') {
          db.USaccounts.query()
        } else if (args.currency === 'GBP') {
          db.UKaccounts.query()
        } else if ...
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Basically, my resolve will be a large set of conditional branches which check for the presence of various combinations of arguments and call the appropriate DB or internal API endpoint with the correct args passed. Is this the correct approach to handling arguments in graphQL?

Comment: Seems like you've defined static queries at the DB level for various filters on accounts... I don't think there's anything wrong with this approach, but the obvious alternative would be to pass the `country`, `currency` args to your DB layer and have it formulate the correct DB query based on those arguments, which would probably reduce your `db` module code if you have a typical database design.  Or you could go in the other direction, and surface your static lists at the top query level.  Instead of just `query { accounts }`, you could have `query { USaccounts, UKaccounts }`.